# Why is my samba domain user created by a bash script behave differently from one created manually?

Tags: linux, windows, active-directory, ldap, samba

I have a samba server which is using LDAP as its backend. The PDC is working as expected as long as I create the users manually. This means that if I use the following command to create a new user, I can log in on a Windows machine using the user bob and I am not asked to change the password:

```
sudo smbldap-useradd -a -P bob
```

Since, I do not have access to cleartext passwords of the users, I use an ldif file to modify the sambaNTPassword attribute of the user. This is the only way I could come up with because I am only provided with the NTLM hash of the password. Nevertheless, the password is then successfully updated and I can log on the Windows machine.

Here is the problem:
users and their hash digests are provided to me in mass. They are first written into a postgresql database. Then I have to run a script that reads list of users (new users) from the database along with its NTLM digest. Since this process should be automated, I have to develop a bash script for this purpose. Here is part of my script that runs the above command:

```
#!/bin/bash    
/usr/bin/expect <<EOD
spawn smbldap-useradd -a -P $username
expect "New password:" { send -- "$tot\n" }
expect "Retype new password:" { send -- "$toto\n" }
EOD
```

The user is successfully created and I can log on the Windows machine with it. The problem is that I receive the following message:

> your password expires today. do you want to change it?

Does anybody where the difference comes from? To me both methods seem identical.

My server:
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Samba: 3.6.3

The following is the LDAP entry of user bob when I create it manually (enter passwords manually) and then update its sambaNTPasssword attribute:

```
$ ldapsearch -x uid=bob
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=mydomain,dc=com> (default) with scope subtree
# filter: uid=bob
# requesting: ALL
#

# bob, Users, mydomain.com
dn: uid=bob,ou=Users,dc=mydomain,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: sambaSamAccount
cn: bob
sn: bob
uid: bob
uidNumber: 1166
gidNumber: 513
homeDirectory: /home/bob
loginShell: /bin/bash
gecos: System User
givenName: bob
sambaLogonTime: 0
sambaLogoffTime: 2147483647
sambaKickoffTime: 2147483647
sambaPwdCanChange: 0
displayName: bob
sambaSID: S-1-5-21-343724861-3572058179-3643679278-3332
sambaLMPassword: B267DF22CB945E3EAAD3B435B51404EE
sambaAcctFlags: [U]
sambaPwdLastSet: 1402503403
sambaPwdMustChange: 1488903403
shadowLastChange: 16232
shadowMax: 1000
sambaNTPassword: FCFC9A2A1E3F4F9F5E1EBA9A4592507E
```

And the following is the LDAP entry of user bob when I create it using the script (I update the sambaNTPassword in this case):

```
# bob, Users, mydomain.com
dn: uid=bob,ou=Users,dc=mydomain,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: sambaSamAccount
cn: bob
sn: bob
uid: bob
uidNumber: 1168
gidNumber: 513
homeDirectory: /home/bob
loginShell: /bin/bash
gecos: System User
givenName: bob
sambaPwdLastSet: 0
sambaLogonTime: 0
sambaLogoffTime: 2147483647
sambaKickoffTime: 2147483647
sambaPwdCanChange: 0
sambaPwdMustChange: 2147483647
displayName: bob
sambaAcctFlags: [UX]
sambaSID: S-1-5-21-343724861-3572058179-3643679278-3336
sambaNTPassword: FCFC9A2A1E3F4F9F5E1EBA9A4592507E
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the man page for `smbldap-useradd`, it sounds like you need to set `-B 0` in your script.
According [to this](http://infrastructure.blueprint.org/Home/List-of-All-Tasks/Assign-new-user-accounts), it will clear the "User must change password" flag on the account.

You may want to review your smb.conf to make sure you don't have any unexpected `smbldap-useradd` settings.